# Why would Google be throwing away emails from virtual domains to virtual domains? postfix

Tags: postfix, virtualization, smtp, gmail

I'm seeing some odd behavior and am hoping someone has seen this as well.

I have a CentOS server running Postfix for virtual domains for my businesses.

It was working well for years and then suddenly recently -- apparently around February 17th 2021 -- it became obvious that I was missing certain emails that people were sending me.

After digging into it a bit, it seems to only happen when someone is sending from their virtual domain to my virtual domain.

I'm at a loss and any suggestions would be great.

Here's a bit more about my configuration and what I'm seeing.

The virtual user table is set up to accept various domains and various users at those domains.  These are all forwarded to Gmail accounts i.e.

user@mycompany.com

goes to

googleusername+user@gmail.com

My friend who is helping me has three different accounts with three different ISPs.  Two of them feature his own business domain, and one is just the basic ISP account. i.e.

friend@ISP.net

friend@hiscompany.com

friend@hisothercompany.com

If he sends email to my business address user@mycompany.com from each of these three accounts, in the mail logs on my server, I see the same three things.  I see my Postfix accept his email, I see the email get requeued for delivery to Google, and I see the delivery to Google.  I see that for each of the three messages.

Here's the strange part.  ONLY the friend@ISP.net message actually shows up in my Gmail inbox.

FWIW I've seen similar behavior from many of my customers i.e. they have trouble emailing my business address and when they either use my "naked" Gmail address or use their personal email, I get it just fine.

Any thoughts, suggestions, ideas most welcome.  I am really at a loss.  The configuration worked perfectly for years.  My best guess is that Google is checking for something now that they weren't doing before and I need to update something in my mail configuration...  this sort of relaying for virtual domains is super common and so I must just be missing something, or there's a new compliance thing that is required now.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: The emails are not in Spam or in any of the random other tabs, like Promotions. I have looked in those places and also done searches to see if they might have been stashed somewhere other than the inbox, to no avail.

EDIT2: Obfuscated snippet from mail log showing three tests to my virtual address, all three being delivered to Google, only one actually showed up in my folders.

```
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: connect from mail-mw2nam10on2139.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.139]
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: setting up TLS connection from mail-mw2nam10on2139.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.139]
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-mw2nam10on2139.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.139]: TLSv1.2 with cipher AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: 9AA2A203F8: client=mail-mw2nam10on2139.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.139]
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/cleanup[7735]: 9AA2A203F8: message-id=<34C9069F-6D71-429D-A536-B5D762233AC2@friendcompanyA.com>
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: 9AA2A203F8: from=<Friend@friendcompanyA.com>, size=10572, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: warning: network_biopair_interop: error writing 44 bytes to the network: Connection reset by peer
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: warning: network_biopair_interop: error writing 31 bytes to the network: Broken pipe
Feb 26 14:54:01 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: disconnect from mail-mw2nam10on2139.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.139]
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: E544422465: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/cleanup[7735]: E544422465: message-id=<34C9069F-6D71-429D-A536-B5D762233AC2@friendcompanyA.com>
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: E544422465: from=<Friend@friendcompanyA.com>, size=11025, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett amavis[6636]: (06636-07) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [40.107.94.139]:51936 [40.107.94.139] <Friend@friendcompanyA.com> -> <mygmail@gmail.com>, Message-ID: <34C9069F-6D71-429D-A536-B5D762233AC2@friendcompanyA.com>, mail_id: WWCNTFsH0GOS, Hits: -1.801, size: 10565, queued_as: E544422465, dkim_sd=selector2-friendcompanyA-onmicrosoft-com:friendcompanyA.onmicrosoft.com, 1272 ms
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7736]: 9AA2A203F8: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, orig_to=<me@mycompany.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.4, delays=0.07/0.02/0/1.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E544422465)
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: 9AA2A203F8: removed
Feb 26 14:54:02 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c09::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb 26 14:54:03 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: setting up TLS connection to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25
Feb 26 14:54:03 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: Trusted TLS connection established to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Feb 26 14:54:03 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: E544422465: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25, delay=0.93, delays=0.01/0.04/0.13/0.75, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1614351180 y17si9268983plh.394 - gsmtp)
Feb 26 14:54:03 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: E544422465: removed
Feb 26 14:54:53 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: connect from mail-bn7nam10on2131.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.92.131]
Feb 26 14:54:53 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: setting up TLS connection from mail-bn7nam10on2131.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.92.131]
Feb 26 14:54:54 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-bn7nam10on2131.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.92.131]: TLSv1.2 with cipher AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Feb 26 14:54:54 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: 43D46203F8: client=mail-bn7nam10on2131.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.92.131]
Feb 26 14:54:54 syd-barrett postfix/cleanup[7735]: 43D46203F8: message-id=<C9DE7C1F-AF5C-42A4-9216-31A151418DFF@friendcompanyB.com>
Feb 26 14:54:54 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: 43D46203F8: from=<Friend@friendcompanyB.com>, size=10836, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 26 14:54:54 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: warning: network_biopair_interop: error writing 44 bytes to the network: Connection reset by peer
Feb 26 14:54:54 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: warning: network_biopair_interop: error writing 31 bytes to the network: Broken pipe
Feb 26 14:54:54 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: disconnect from mail-bn7nam10on2131.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.92.131]
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: E1D8722465: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/cleanup[7735]: E1D8722465: message-id=<C9DE7C1F-AF5C-42A4-9216-31A151418DFF@friendcompanyB.com>
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: E1D8722465: from=<Friend@friendcompanyB.com>, size=11289, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c09::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett amavis[5574]: (05574-12) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [40.107.92.131]:15723 [40.107.92.131] <Friend@friendcompanyB.com> -> <mygmail@gmail.com>, Message-ID: <C9DE7C1F-AF5C-42A4-9216-31A151418DFF@friendcompanyB.com>, mail_id: WHaVv9MpPDf0, Hits: -1.901, size: 10829, queued_as: E1D8722465, dkim_sd=selector2-friendcompanyBcom-onmicrosoft-com:friendcompanyBcom.onmicrosoft.com, 1370 ms
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7736]: 43D46203F8: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, orig_to=<me@mycompany.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.7, delays=0.32/0/0/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E1D8722465)
Feb 26 14:54:55 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: 43D46203F8: removed
Feb 26 14:54:56 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: setting up TLS connection to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25
Feb 26 14:54:56 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: Trusted TLS connection established to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Feb 26 14:54:56 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: E1D8722465: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25, delay=0.54, delays=0.01/0/0.13/0.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1614351232 u11si8933302pgj.302 - gsmtp)
Feb 26 14:54:56 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: E1D8722465: removed
Feb 26 15:00:59 syd-barrett postfix/anvil[7728]: statistics: max cache size 2 at Feb 26 14:54:01
Feb 26 14:55:27 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: connect from resqmta-po-02v.sys.comcast.net[96.114.154.161]
Feb 26 14:55:27 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: setting up TLS connection from resqmta-po-02v.sys.comcast.net[96.114.154.161]
Feb 26 14:55:27 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: Anonymous TLS connection established from resqmta-po-02v.sys.comcast.net[96.114.154.161]: TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Feb 26 14:55:27 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7732]: 9985D203F8: client=resqmta-po-02v.sys.comcast.net[96.114.154.161]
Feb 26 14:55:27 syd-barrett postfix/cleanup[7735]: 9985D203F8: message-id=<C1EEC46C-4850-420D-A278-64EBE1EE6D29@comcast.net>
Feb 26 14:55:27 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: 9985D203F8: from=<friend@comcast.net>, size=4953, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: DF9A122479: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/cleanup[7735]: DF9A122479: message-id=<C1EEC46C-4850-420D-A278-64EBE1EE6D29@comcast.net>
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: DF9A122479: from=<friend@comcast.net>, size=5406, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/smtpd[7738]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c09::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett amavis[6636]: (06636-08) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [96.114.154.161]:32912 [67.170.123.168] <friend@comcast.net> -> <mygmail@gmail.com>, Message-ID: <C1EEC46C-4850-420D-A278-64EBE1EE6D29@comcast.net>, mail_id: PzSxJQ1_ttxt, Hits: -3.781, size: 4952, queued_as: DF9A122479, dkim_sd=20190202a:comcast.net, 1240 ms
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7736]: 9985D203F8: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, orig_to=<me@mycompany.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.3, delays=0.09/0/0/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as DF9A122479)
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: 9985D203F8: removed
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: setting up TLS connection to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25
Feb 26 14:55:28 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: Trusted TLS connection established to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Feb 26 14:55:29 syd-barrett postfix/smtp[7739]: DF9A122479: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26]:25, delay=0.38, delays=0.01/0/0.1/0.28, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1614351265 o15si7640511pgu.280 - gsmtp)
Feb 26 14:55:29 syd-barrett postfix/qmgr[7647]: DF9A122479: removed
```

Comment: Check your Gmail Spam folder.

Comment: The emails are not in Spam or in any of the random other tabs, like Promotions.  I have looked in those places and also done searches to see if they might have been stashed somewhere other than the inbox, to no avail.

Comment: OK, show the relevant Postfix logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Here you go, sorry for the delay. Email addresses and machine names obfuscated, otherwise unchanged.  Added to the original post, too long for a comment.

Comment: Hmm. Your mail has 100% absolutely been delivered to Gmail. What happened after that is something you'll have to ask Google; we have absolutely no way of knowing.

Comment: OK, my original question stands then. Has anyone seen this sort of behavior from Google and if so, what changes resulted in Google delivering the mail properly?  Alternatively has anyone seen anything similar from any ISP?  Or perhaps some sort of best practices and/or list of things to check?

Comment: One thing you want to verify is DNS (&DNSSEC) for all domains mentioned in the mail headers. While I do not know how Google specifically handles these cases, temporary errors in resolving names can and does sometimes lead to mail spending substantially more time in limbo while spam checking utilities attempt to lookup how to classify them.

Comment: I believe I fixed this, apparently it's a somewhat known issue with virtual alias forwarding to Google that Google may see the forward, look at the original sender, see the forwarded email is from a server not on the SPF list for the original sending domain, and silently dispose of the email, never to be seen.

Comment: The apparent solution is to use SRS so that Google sees the email as being sent from the forwarding server, and checks the SPF for the forwarding domain.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed this, apparently it's a somewhat known issue with virtual alias forwarding to Google that Google may see the forward, look at the original sender, see the forwarded email is from a server not on the SPF list for the original sending domain, and silently dispose of the email, never to be seen.

The apparent solution is to use SRS so that Google sees the email as being sent from the forwarding server, and checks the SPF for the forwarding domain.

I say apparent because A) the solution has only been in place for a short time and B) because I couldn't enable SRS on that system, I ended up building a new mail server, and while I was at it, making sure SPF, DKIM, DMARC are all configured, and then also adding code for SRS.